Как полностью удалить то что было установлено при попытке установить homebrew на macOS 14.5?
Решил установить Homebrew на свой MacOS 14.5, но столкнулся с проблемами. Во время установки у меня пропало интернет-соединение, и загрузка Command Line Tools for Xcode прервалась. Теперь у меня на компьютере непонятно что установлено, а сам процесс установки Homebrew завершился с ошибками. В общем, я передумал использовать homebrew, но не хочу случайно удалить что-то лишнее, чтобы не сделать хуже.
Пока никаких попыток удаления не предпринимал, так как опасаюсь зацепить что-то важное для системы. Хотелось бы узнать, как правильно удалить всё, что Homebrew успел установить, включая любые связанные с ним файлы и каталоги.
Вот терминал:
Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/install -d -o root -g wheel -m 0755 /opt/homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod ug=rwx /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod go-w /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown almasakzhigitov /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/etc /opt/homebrew/include /opt/homebrew/lib /opt/homebrew/sbin /opt/homebrew/share /opt/homebrew/var /opt/homebrew/opt /opt/homebrew/share/zsh /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked /opt/homebrew/Cellar /opt/homebrew/Caskroom /opt/homebrew/Frameworks
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R almasakzhigitov:admin /opt/homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /Users/almasakzhigitov/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Users/almasakzhigitov/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R almasakzhigitov /Users/almasakzhigitov/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Searching online for the Command Line Tools
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
==> Installing Command Line Tools for Xcode-16.1
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate -i Command\ Line\ Tools\ for\ Xcode-16.1
Software Update Tool

Finding available software

Downloading Command Line Tools for Xcode
Error downloading Command Line Tools for Xcode: The operation couldn’t be completed. (PKDownloadError error 8.)
Done.

Error downloading updates.
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
Password:
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
almasakzhigitov@Almass-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew --version
zsh: command not found: brew
almasakzhigitov@Almass-MacBook-Pro ~ % 

Помогите разобраться, что нужно удалить, чтобы вернуть систему в исходное состояние, как до установки Homebrew.
